# Counting results from different tables in one query

Tags: mysql

I have `orders`, `order_attachments`, `order_preship_check`, `order_preship_check_attachment`, `order_log`, `order_log_attachments` tables

The only common thing in these columns are order_id. Right now in the query I am only checking those order_attachments which are type 1 and type 2 using the following query

```
SELECT
    COUNT(file_id) AS totalFiles
FROM
    orders_files
WHERE
    order_id = '88125'
AND attachment_type IN ('1', '2')
```

So if it returns I show an ATTACHMENTS icon with that order. Now I need to combine preship attachments and log attachments in this as well. There are no additional checks, individual queries for both are as follows

```
SELECT
    COUNT(file_id) AS totalFiles
FROM
    orders_preship_check_attachment
WHERE
    order_id = '88125'
```

and

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS totalFiles
FROM
    orders_log_attachment
WHERE
    order_id = '88125'
```

I need to combine these 3 queries in one query. So if each table have 1 records, I just need to get the count of 3, even 3 is not important. Means if any of these records have attachments I need to show the icon, TRUE or FALSE. I hope it makes it more clear

Comment: If you're trying to get a total, you could just add the numbers. If you're trying to get a result set with three rows, one per count, try using UNION. If you're trying to get a result set with one column per count query, just put them all in the same query as subqueries or something.

Comment: i just need to check if there are attachments or not, no other details are required

Comment: Then just add them. Like, do `SELECT (query1) + (query2) + (query3) AS 'total'`, where the various queryN things are the queries you already have. I'm fairly sure that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```sql
SELECT SUM(totalFiles) AS totalFiles
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(file_id) AS totalFiles
      FROM orders_files
     WHERE order_id = '88125' AND
           attachment_type IN ('1', '2')
     UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(file_id) AS totalFiles
      FROM orders_preship_check_attachment
     WHERE order_id = '88125'
     UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(id) AS totalFiles
      FROM orders_log_attachment
     WHERE order_id = '88125'
    ) t
```

or

```sql
SELECT COUNT(file_id) AS totalFiles
  FROM (
    SELECT file_id
      FROM orders_files
     WHERE order_id = '88125' AND
           attachment_type IN ('1', '2')
     UNION ALL
    SELECT file_id
      FROM orders_preship_check_attachment
     WHERE order_id = '88125'
     UNION ALL
    SELECT id
      FROM orders_log_attachment
     WHERE order_id = '88125'
    ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION or UNION ALL but this must have the same type and number of columns.

Example code:

```
    SELECT 'Customer' AS type, id, name FROM customer
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Supplier', id, name FROM supplier
```

If your query contains different number of columns try using joins.